# Have err when mvn -Prelease-all -DskipTests clean install -U

Tags: maven, rocketmq

Problem as title says

the RocketMQ version i use is incubator-rocketmq-release-4.0.0-incubating 
downloading from https://github.com/apache/incubator-rocketmq/tree/release-4.0.0-incubating

it has some err when mvn -Prelease-all -DskipTests clean install -U

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache RocketMQ 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-remoting 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-common 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-client 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-store 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-srvutil 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-broker 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-tools 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-namesrv 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-example 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-filtersrv 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] rocketmq-test 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache RocketMQ 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ rocketmq-all ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-ban-circular-dependencies) @ rocketmq-all ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ rocketmq-all ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.8/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.8-runtime.jar=destfile=/usr/local/rocketMQ/incubator-rocketmq-release-4.0.0-incubating/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (process-resource-bundles) @ rocketmq-all ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache RocketMQ 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT .......... FAILURE [  2.688 s]
[INFO] rocketmq-remoting 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-common 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-client 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-store 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-srvutil 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-broker 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-tools 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-namesrv 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-example 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-filtersrv 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] rocketmq-test 4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.335 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-10T14:49:16+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/43M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (process-resource-bundles) on project rocketmq-all: Error finding remote resources manifests: /usr/local/rocketMQ/incubator-rocketmq-release-4.0.0-incubating/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException



[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (process-resource-bundles) on project rocketmq-all: Error finding remote resources manifests: /usr/local/rocketMQ/incubator-rocketmq-release-4.0.0-incubating/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (process-resource-bundles) on project rocketmq-all: Error finding remote resources manifests
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error finding remote resources manifests
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.remote.ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.processResourceBundles(ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.java:1238)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.remote.ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.execute(ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.java:520)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/rocketMQ/incubator-rocketmq-release-4.0.0-incubating/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.remote.ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.processResourceBundles(ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.java:1146)
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: Try Mavens -e and/or -X options to get more details on the error.

Comment: The problem seemed to be located here: `/usr/local/rocketMQ/incubator-rocketmq-release-4.0.0-incubating/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE (No such file or directory) ` .  Did you had issue with the online connections ?

Comment: i have access to Internet, i am using alibaba cloud linux server  
when i use maven lean and install at first time,it generate a folder named target,but later it doesn't

Comment: I have used the above command. but it works fine.